# Design to approach Scheduler with time consuming HTTP request

Tags: rest, http, mule, scheduled-tasks, mulesoft

I need to design a flow which should trigger the scheduler for every 3 min and it will fire an HTTP request. The HTTP request is a time-consuming operation say it has to fetch/write some 15-50 MB file. While the request is still getting processed I don't want the scheduler to trigger the request again.
What is the best way to design this flow using Mulesoft?

one solution I could think of is wrapping the HTTP with async scope. But it will still allow the scheduler to fire next requests.

```
<async doc:name="Async">
  <!-- One or more processors here -->
</async>
```

Answer (score 3):

One way you can achieve this by setting the maximum concurrency of the scheduled flow to 1, which means that no parallel executions of the flow will be permitted.

A simplified example (in mule 4) which attempts to trigger every second, but the flow takes 5 seconds to complete. Only every fifth event will be processed.

```
<flow name="sandboxFlow" maxConcurrency="1">
    <scheduler doc:name="Scheduler">
        <scheduling-strategy >
            <fixed-frequency />
        </scheduling-strategy>
    </scheduler>
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Log Start" message="Start"/>
    <scripting:execute doc:name="Sleep" engine="groovy">
        <scripting:code >sleep(5000);</scripting:code>
    </scripting:execute>
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Log End" message="Finish"/>
</flow>
```

An issue with this is that you will get an error message for every time the scheduler fires while the flow is processing a previous job, which looks a bit nasty.

```
********************************************************************************
Message               : Flow 'sandboxFlow' is unable to accept new events at this time
Error type            : MULE:FLOW_BACK_PRESSURE
Element               : sandboxFlow @ sandbox:sandbox.xml:22
Element XML           : <flow name="sandboxFlow" doc:id="a01c0292-b993-437b-976f-92903703fbae" maxConcurrency="1">
...
```

If you want to avoid the error message in the logs without a blanket rule in your logging properties, you could do this with queues and breaking it into two flows.

```
<flow name="sandboxFlow">
    <scheduler doc:name="Scheduler">
        <scheduling-strategy >
            <fixed-frequency frequency="2000"/>
        </scheduling-strategy>
    </scheduler>
    <vm:publish queueName="controlQ" doc:name="Publish" config-ref="VM_Config"/>
</flow>
<flow name="sandboxFlow2" maxConcurrency="1">
    <vm:listener doc:name="Listener" config-ref="VM_Config" numberOfConsumers="1" queueName="controlQ"/>
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Log Start" message="Start" />
    <scripting:execute doc:name="Execute" engine="groovy">
        <scripting:code >sleep(5000);</scripting:code>
    </scripting:execute>
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Log End" message="Finish" />
</flow>
```

The first flow runs on the schedule and every time it fires it just places the trigger onto a queue and finishes.

The flow which reads off the queue is singe-threaded so will only run one at a time, and when there is a trigger message on the queue. This achieves the same behaviour but without the error message in the logs.

Hopefully that helps!